# Sybase Database, Data is nowhere to be found?

Tags: sql, database, sybase

Here's my situation. We have an application that uses sybase to store it's data on the back-end. 
Please refer to my screenshots below for better understanding of what I'm talking about.

In our application, we have some custom "tabs" (columns in the db) which are supposed to contain data on the db tables. When opening and viewing in the application, these tabs contain data (so they must reside somewhere...), however when you query the table they're supposedly residing under, there's no data to be found. These columns should not contain all null values!

In this example, "trainer" is one of the columns which should contain data. I do a [sp_columns @column_name = 'trainer'] and see that it supposedly resides under table "user_tab_data" (screenshot 1).

Expanding user_tab_data in our sql browser, we see the data points we need to query (training date, training course, trainer, etc.), however when querying for the values, nothing comes up! We can see when opening the application that there is indeed data stored somewhere though.

Is there anything I can do to locate this? Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you

[sp_columns to find table name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKDae.png)

[query showing that table contains null values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCBq2.png)

Comment: Investigate the source code perhaps? Check your connection strings?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I don't think that's it... It has to be somewhere that I just cannot find... for some reason. I checked all relevant tables and nothing. Maybe somebody knows of some stored procedure or a query I can use to search for some of the data points that are missing but should be stored somewhere?

Comment: Assuming this is Sybase ASE ... I'd start by running your (search) queries via the `isql` command line tool; you need to eliminate the middleware/GUI (application, sql browser) as a potential issue and get as direct a connection as you can to the actual data ... and you're not going to get any closer, and more basic, than with the `isql` command line tool

Comment: Thanks for both of you taking the time to comment. I can't believe I spent hours banging my head against the wall before I realized the simple solution to this non-issue. lol.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing. I figured it out. There was just so many entries on the table that you could scroll for hours and not see any entries where the columns I wanted had any data.

I had to do 'is not NULL' to pull only the ones I wanted to see.

Duh.